# RangeWidget on Django FloatRangeField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to create a ModelForm which includes a FloatRangeField. However, when POSTing the form with a decimal number, the form validation doesn't go through and it says I should enter the nearest whole number.

I tried to override the behaviour of the widget using the following code:

```html
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'value': RangeWidget(NumberInput(attrs={'step': 'any'})),
        }
```

However, this does not return the desired behaviour, the problem mentioned above persists. How can I get to the correct behaviour. I'm using django-crispy-forms but if I render the form in a non-crispy way, the problems persist.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the form was part of a formset. So overriding the widget in the ModelForm did not work. I had to change it in the inlineformset_factory:

```
MyModelFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    ParentModel,
    MyModel,
    fields='__all__',
    widgets = {
            'value': RangeWidget(NumberInput(attrs={'step': 'any'})),
        }
)
```